# C Socket Programming: reopen and reconnect socket

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets

I am testing out my code for reconnection in case the connection drop. However I'm facing some Segmentation Error after the socket is re-opened and re-connected.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>             //socket
#include <bluetooth/bluetooth.h>    //bluetooth
#include <bluetooth/rfcomm.h>       //bluetooth
#include <string.h>                 //strlen
#include <arpa/inet.h>              //inet_addr

struct BTConnection {
   int client;
   int s;
   int retry;
};

struct BTConnection bt_1;

void *bt_connect(void *arg);
void *bt_send(void *arg);
void *bt_receive(void *arg);

void *bt_connect(void *arg)
{
    struct BTConnection *connect = (struct BTConnection*)arg;

    struct sockaddr_rc loc_addr = { 0 }, rem_addr = { 0 };
    char buf[1024] = { 0 };
    socklen_t opt = sizeof(rem_addr);

    // allocate socket
    connect->s = socket(AF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTPROTO_RFCOMM);

    // bind socket to port 1 of the first available
    // local bluetooth adapter
    loc_addr.rc_family = AF_BLUETOOTH;
    loc_addr.rc_bdaddr = *BDADDR_ANY;
    loc_addr.rc_channel = (uint8_t) 1;
    bind(connect->s, (struct sockaddr *)&loc_addr, sizeof(loc_addr));

    // put socket into listening mode
    listen(connect->s, 1);

    // accept one connection
    connect->client = accept(connect->s, (struct sockaddr *)&rem_addr, &opt);
    ba2str( &rem_addr.rc_bdaddr, buf );

    return 0;
}

void *bt_send(void *arg)
{
    struct BTConnection *connect = (struct BTConnection*)arg;
    char buf[1024] = { 0 };
    int bytes_read, retry;

    puts("[Bluetooth] Sending data to device...");
    while(1) {
        .....

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mDataMutex);
        puts("send mutex in");
        while(connect->retry != 0);
        puts("send mutex out");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mDataMutex);

        if(write(connect->client, return_msg, strlen(return_msg)) < 0) {
            ....
            puts("Error reading from socket");
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mDataMutex);
            puts("send mutex");
            if(connect->retry == 0)
                connect->retry = 2;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mDataMutex);
            puts("send mutex end");

            pthread_mutex_lock(&mDataMutex);
            if(connect->retry == 2) {
                close(connect->client);
                close(connect->s);
                bt_connect(&connect);
                connect->retry = 0;
                puts("send retry success");
            } else
                retry = 1;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mDataMutex);

            if(retry == 1)
            {
                puts("bluetooth send retrying in 8 secs");
                sleep(8);
            }
        } else
            retry = 0;

        // clear buffer
        memset(return_msg,0,sizeof return_msg);
        memset(temp,0,sizeof temp);
        // set to send data every second
        sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;
}

void *bt_receive(void *arg)
{
    // similar as above
}

int main(void)
{
    bt_1.retry = 0;
    int rc;
    void *status;
    pthread_t bt_connect_thread, bt_send_thread, bt_receive_thread;
    pthread_attr_t attr;

    /* Initialize and set thread detached attribute */
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);

    // Create BT connect thread and start it
    rc = pthread_create(&bt_connect_thread, &attr, bt_connect, (void *)&bt_1);
    if (rc)
    {
        printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
        return (-1);
    }

    rc = pthread_join(bt_connect_thread, &status);
    rc = pthread_create(&bt_send_thread, &attr, bt_send, (void *)&bt_1);
    rc = pthread_create(&bt_receive_thread, &attr, bt_receive, (void *)&bt_1);

    rc = pthread_join(bt_send_thread, &status);
    rc = pthread_join(bt_receive_thread, &status);
    close(bt_1.client);
    close(bt_1.s);
    pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);

    return 0;
}
```

The code may look a little messy in sending and receiving part as I was using mutex to check and debug the output.

This is the output I am getting:

```
[Bluetooth] Allocating socket... Done!
[Bluetooth] Bind socket... Done!
[Bluetooth] Waiting for incoming connections...
[Bluetooth] Accepted connection from 44:6D:6C:6D:1B:BC
[Bluetooth] Bluetooth connection thread completed
[Bluetooth] Receiving data from device...
rcv mutex in
rcv mutex out
[Bluetooth] Sending data to device...
send mutex in
send mutex out
send mutex in
send mutex out
[Bluetooth-Receive] Error reading from socket
receive mutex
receive mutex end
[Bluetooth-Receive] Connections closed. Reconnecting...
[Bluetooth] Allocating socket... Done!
[Bluetooth] Bind socket... Done!
[Bluetooth] Waiting for incoming connections...
[Bluetooth] Accepted connection from 44:6D:6C:6D:1B:BC
[Bluetooth] Bluetooth connection thread completed
Segmentation fault
```

I am not sure what is wrong since I did ensure that i close the socket before re-opening it. Any help/guidance? Thanks!

Edit: Not sure if bt_send is jamming it since it didn't print out `[Bluetooth-Send] Error reading from socket` when I'm sending test data automatically every second... (and both send and receive are running simultaneously)

PS. New to C and Socket Programming

Comment: If you run in this `gdb` (or some other debugger), it will tell you exactly what line of code is causing the segfault.

Comment: I would suspect the `close` part...

Comment: You should probably check the return value of `bind()` for failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void *bt_connect(void *arg)
{
    struct BTConnection *connect = (struct BTConnection*)arg;
```

Okay, so we need to call `bt_connect` passing it a pointer to a `BTConnection`.

```
    struct BTConnection *connect = (struct BTConnection*)arg;
...
                bt_connect(&connect);
```

Since `connect` is a pointer to a `BTConnection`, `&connect` is a pointer to a pointer. So why are we passing it to `bt_connect`?

Comment: Hi @david-schwartz thanks for pointing that out. In this case, should i be passing the global variable bt_1 instead? I'm sorry if it sounds like asking you to write the code out but it would definitey help me better if you can add in the corrected code so I can learn from there and test it out

Comment: Just remove the `&`.

Comment: thanks so much, works like a charm!